# RedirectToAction not working with $.post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem. I'm trying to redirect my application using a controller method, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSelected(string Selected, string NewRoleID)
    {
        var StringSelected = Selected.Split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < StringSelected.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (StringSelected[i] == "true")
            {
                R_ROLEMENU newMenu = new R_ROLEMENU();
                newMenu.RoleID = int.Parse(NewRoleID);
                newMenu.MenuID = i + 1;
                var existing = (from item in db.RoleMenus
                                where (item.RoleID == newMenu.RoleID && item.MenuID == newMenu.MenuID)
                                select item).ToArray();
                if (existing.Count() == 0)
                {
                    db.RoleMenus.Add(newMenu);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                R_ROLEMENU oldMenu = new R_ROLEMENU();
                oldMenu.RoleID = int.Parse(NewRoleID);
                oldMenu.MenuID = i + 1;
                var existing = (from item in db.RoleMenus
                                where (item.RoleID == oldMenu.RoleID && item.MenuID == oldMenu.MenuID)
                                select item).ToArray();
                if (existing.Count() != 0)
                {
                    db.RoleMenus.Remove(existing[0]);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Home");
    }
```

And I'm calling the method with jquery, like this:

```
$.post("/m_menu/getselected?selected=" + selectedmenus + "&newroleid=" + roleid, function () {
                    //todo
        });
```

The problem is, the application keeps redirected to index page instead of the Logout action in Home Controller. What am I doing wrong? The rest of the code within the controller is running fine, it's just the redirection that's not working. Please help, thank you

Comment: it look like route issue, but is hard to determine as the code that you provide look fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is an ajax call **RedirectToAction** will simply return the action called view as response of post you have to redirect via jquery in **$.post** call back function:

In Action instead of:

```
return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Home");
```

do:

```
return Content(Url.Action("Logout", "Home"));
```

and in call back of **$.post** do this:

```
$.post("/m_menu/getselected?selected=" + selectedmenus + "&newroleid=" + roleid, function (response) {
                  window.location =  response;
        });
```

or call call javascript at the end of action:

```
var script = "window.loaction ='"+Url.Action("Logout","Home")+"' ;";
return JavaScript(script);
```